# DOM is not being uploaded for my Etch-A-Sketch board

Tags: javascript, html, dom, error-handling, null

Receiving the following error when trying to run the below code:  Null value on line 9 due to appendChild.  Is my code not reading the etch id?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src ="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="etch"></div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

```
let num = 16;

let etch = document.getElementById("etch");

function board () {
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add("row");
        etch.appendChild(row);

    for(let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        let column = document.createElement("div");
        column.classList.add("column");
        row.appendChild(column);
      }

    }
 }

 board();
```

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#etch{
    margin: 27px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: black 2px solid;
}

.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: silver;
}

.row{
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: white 1px solid;
}
```

I am able to get my code to work in MDN playground earlier without adding external js or css files.  Not sure what's going on here.  I would appreciate any help.  Beginner here.

Comment: I've tried that and still receive this error:   Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at board (c:\Users\wgreu\OneDrive\Desktop\repos\etchasketch\script.js:9:14)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\wgreu\OneDrive\Desktop\repos\etchasketch\script.js:20:2)     and this error:   Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Identifier 'num' has already been declared
    at (program) (c:\Users\wgreu\OneDrive\Desktop\repos\etchasketch\script.js:1:1)  @Yogi

Comment: @yogi are you seeing the silver background and white border square divs?

Comment: @Yogi still not seeing anything.   Like I said, works fine on MDN playground

Comment: I can see the divs fine in MDN with the height and width.  The flex-grow should be enought.  @Ray Wallace

Answer (score 1):

I do not get the null error ether.

Like Yogi mentioned, if you want to see the created divs, you need to set the the width and height.
Also, you are missing a "display: flex;" style for .row

style.css changes:

```
.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;

    background-color: silver;

  /* RWWJ */
  min-width:  64px;
  min-height: 64px;
  border: white 1px solid;
}

.row{
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: white 1px solid;

  /* RWWJ */
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by editing my `<head>`.  Specifically, I added:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```